# Outliers in a PCA score plot

Tags: r, pca, data-visualization, outliers

I have this dataset of 104 tissue samples from two different types of tumors (B and C) along and 182 observations (gene expression profile). I do not need to understand the underlying biological theory for this but I do have to carry out a PCA to see if I can reduce the data to make reading it easier. I standardized the data first and carried out my PCA. Having done so, I got the following score plot:
[image]

I noticed the 6 samples not grouped together and using *factoextra*, I was able to find out which samples these are:

```
ind <- get_pca_ind(pca1)
ind_df <- as.data.frame(ind$contrib[, 1:2]) # contribution of each individual/sample to the PCA space (PC1 and PC2)
```

I then opened the data frame and sorted according to highest contribution to PC1 first and found out that samples 71 to 76 (which are all C type tumors) are the, for lack of a better word, outliers.

What can I do from here? What steps can I take and what inference can be made from this? I can't just remove them from my dataset as it would completely change the analysis.

Comment: You have found, that type C tumors in general have lower values in PC1 and that there seems to be a formerly unknown subgroup of type C tumors that score much less on PC1 and variate much more on PC2 then the rest of the type C tumors. Go check if those six have something else in common.

Comment: The 6 outliers seem to lie on a smooth curve.  Are they an artifact of something like the measurement process?